# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

After recent firebase update the console throws this error.
Here is the code that causes the problem.
I am using firebase_database: ^1.0.0.

```
User.dict(String key, Map<String, dynamic> dict) {
final username = dict["username"] as String;
final imageUrl = dict["image_url"] as String;

this.id = key;
this.username = username;
this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
```

}

Comment: Please add sufficient context in order for others to help you. Consider including what package(s) or libraries you are using, what versions, and an example of how your code fails. This snippet alone is not enough to help you.

Comment: What line causes the exception?

Comment: I guess you are giving it a HashMap (mostly json) when it needs a Map<String, dynamic>.

Comment: User.dict(String key, Map<String, dynamic> dict) { causes an error.

Comment: This constructor declaration is not causing the error. The declaration is fine. Some code somewhere is *calling* the constructor with a map of type `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`. You need to find that code and fix it, or change the parameter type of `dict` to `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`.

Comment: After the recent database update it looks like the data retrieved from firebase is of type Map<dynamic, dynamic> instead of Map<String, dynamic> as it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

Use **String** instead of dynamic.